# How to prevent other servers from connecting to a local hazelcast instance

Tags: security, spring-security, hazelcast

I want to use hazelcast as a local-only inter-JVM shared cache. Or put another way, I want to run a secure/private instance.

Is this possible? If so, how?

If it matters, it will be spring-managed.

The motivation is that confidential data will be stored in hazelcast and I want to protect it from external attacks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define your own Group configuration credentials which would be needed to connect to your cluster.

```
<hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
```

Best practices:

1. Always define your own Hazelcast xml/spring configuration instead of using the default one from the jar file
2. Better to make use of TCP/IP network configuration wherever possible instead of multicast, so your cluster won't collide with others.
3. Define custom group credentials, as mentioned above.

Comment: But a cluster of machines, which are all deployed with the same config, will be able to connect to each other. Can I restrict connections to only come from `127.0.0.1` or something?

Comment: Yes, by making use of TCP/IP network config and mentioning the list of IP addresses(In this case, just localhost). It also takes regex, so you can even mention as 127.0.0.* to have the nodes join the cluster from all the IP address under that range.

Comment: For the benefit of people looking for this in later versions of hazelcast, 'group password' feature was not intended for security purpose. To avoid the confusion, it was removed starting v3.8.2. More details here - https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/11667#issuecomment-422670245